# Finding the residues of $\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

There are two obvious poles for $\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^n}$: $i$ and $-i$. Then I tried to compute the residue at these poles,
$$\text {Res}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1+z^2)^n}, i\right)=\lim_{z \rightarrow i} \dfrac{z-i}{(1+z^2)^n}$$
$$\text {Res} (f(z),i)=\lim_{z \rightarrow i} \dfrac{1}{(z+i)^n (z-i)^{n-1}}$$ which is probably an indeterminate form. However, I guess the residues should exist. Where is the mistake?

Comment: The pole is of order $n$ at $z=i$.

Comment: Yes, you need to calculated $\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\frac{(z-i)^{n}}{(1+z^2)^n}$

Comment: @weymarandres is right. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles).

Comment: @J.G. i forgot $\frac{1}{n!}$ sorry, and thank you!!

Comment: @weymarandres Isn't it $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry again. And thank you @J.G.